# Exception specification in C++11 lambda Functions

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

With named functions, exceptions that could be thrown can be specified, as in

```
void func(void) throw (string);
```

How can exceptions be specified in C++ lambda functions?

Comment: Exception specification has been deprecated in C++0X which I did not know of previously.

Comment: `throw()` is deprecated, but `noexcept` is also an exception specification - and is decidedly not deprecated.

Comment: @Barry: Looks like with g++ -std=C++0X, I can still use throw with no compilation errors. " [](int x) throw (string) {} " is compiling just fine

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean won't compile *now*. It means you should stop using it because eventually it won't.

Answer (score 2):

Same way really. The relevant grammar for a lambda in [expr.prim.lambda] is:

> *lambda-expression*:
>       *lambda-introducer* *lambda-declarator*<sub>opt</sub> *compound-statement*
>
> *lambda-introducer*:
>       `[` *lambda-capture*<sub>opt</sub> `]`
>
> *lambda-declarator*:
>       `(` *parameter-declaration-clause* `)` `mutable`<sub>opt</sub>
>               *exception-specification*<sub>opt</sub> *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *trailing-return-type*<sub>opt</sub>

You can provide an optional *exception-specification* after the parameters. For instance:

```
auto never_throws = []() noexcept {
    return 5;
};

int i = never_throws(); // won't throw
```